# Using Rank Function In MySQL results in an error

Tags: rank, mysql-5.7

I am following along on the tutorial for MYSQL to produce a query that ranks. I am following the tutorial [linked](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/)

When i run their code at this point i get an error. I have changed the code slightly to reflect my permissions on my DB

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
    val INT
);

INSERT INTO t(val)
VALUES(1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5);


SELECT 
    *
FROM
    t;

SELECT
    val,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    t;
```

The error message when i run the third SQL is

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT
    val,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    t

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    t' at line 3

        ORDER BY val
^
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.03s
```

Am i missing a setup on my DB to enable ranking?

Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Hi @The Impaler, The version is `VERSION()
5.7.25`

Comment: The `RANK()` function is supported starting on MySQL 8.x.